# How to optimize the insertion of an entry with multiple Strings and Images into a SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, insert

I defined a method to add an entry in my database helper class and insert data into database using it, but it is not working.  This is my method defined in databasehelper class:

```
 public void createchannelEntry(ChannelPoster channel) {
        openDB();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channel.getPoster().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_POSTER, out.toByteArray());            
        cv.put(KEY_CHANNEL, channel.getChannel());
        cv.put(KEY_PATH, channel.getPath());
        cv.put(KEY_DBLINK, channel.getDBlink());

        mDb.insert(channelS_TABLE, null, cv);
        closeDB();
    }
```

this is how I insert data

```
Bitmap sherlock = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sherlock);

mDB.createchannelEntry(new ChannelPoster(sherlock, "aa" ,"ll"  ,"ha" ));
```

and I have a JavaBean for holding an entry

```
public class ChannelPoster {
    private Bitmap poster;
    private String channel;
    private String path;
    private String dblink;

    public ChannelPoster(Bitmap pi, String c, String p, String d) {
        poster = pi;
        channel = c;
        path = p;
        dblink = d;
    }

    public Bitmap getPoster() { return poster; }
    public String getChannel() { return channel; }
    public String getPath() { return path; }
    public String getDBlink() { return dblink; }
}
```

And because I am adding entries one by one, the program runs very slow, so it's there a faster way to insert many entries? like get all of them in one event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest **not saving the images in the database**, but rather saving them as files, and saving a **path to them** in the database (using a normal `TEXT` field).

If you don't want to do that, there are two things that will still greatly improve the speed of your processing:

- Open and close the database **only once** around all your inserts
- Use a **transaction**

Something like that:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openDB();
db.beginTransaction();

try {
    // Add here the loop with all your inserts
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();  // will rollback and cancel the inserts if not marked as successful
    db.close();
}
```

(the `finally` is there to make sure you close the transaction and the connection even if it somehow fails during the inserts: in this case **ALL** your inserts will be cancelled)

Comment: Can u tell how how I put a path to images in the database like you said?